# Typescript - Generic Type - static key - Can we get the value from a static key in a type?

Tags: typescript, generics, types, key

Let's assume we have this code, what should be the best way to solve this type issue ?

```
type TypeA = {
  entityType: 'Type_A'
};

type TypeB = {
  entityType: 'Type_B'
};

type TypeAB = TypeA | TypeB;

const getOnlySubTypeTInArray = <T extends TypeAB>(TypeABs: TypeAB[]) => TypeABs.filter<T>(
  (doc: TypeAB): doc is T => doc.entityType === T.entityType,
);

const getTypeABs = (docs: TypeAB[]) : { typeAs: TypeA[], typeBs: TypeB[] } => ({
  typeAs: getOnlySubTypeTInArray(docs),
  typeBs: getOnlySubTypeTInArray(docs),
});
```

`T.entityType` create this error : 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)

I would like that the line with `{ typeAs: TypeA[], types: TypeB[] }` infer automatically the type of getOnlySubTypeTInArray without the need of specifying the type.

Comment: I'm confused on what you're trying to accomplish with the equality check in `getSubTypes`.

Comment: What ***is*** the type issue?

Comment: I updated the thread to answer your questions

Comment: Types don't exist at runtime; you need to pass a value to your function if you want to check it.  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WP92qw) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining it; if not, what am I missing? (If you reply, please @jcalz mention me if you want me to be notified)

Comment: @jcalz My concern was to be able to get the "static" value of a type but if this isn't possible, Yes it does meet my needs! Thanks !